# I run my application getting message unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, inflate-exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle, PID: 4682
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle/com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Linearlayout
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Linearlayout
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
      at com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:78)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Linearlayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144) 
      at com.jawlatour.apimapgoogle.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:78) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Linearlayout
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 25 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: xml code and java code and manifest code is needed

Comment: i think there is problem in your xml code, but need to see java and xml codes both

Comment: post ur xml please

Comment: It's `LinearLayout` not `Linearlayout` .

Answer (score 1):

your class name is wrong in your xml its should be

`<LinearLayout>`

and yourlog saying you are using

`<Linearlayout>`

so please change it and try !

Comment: This answer is correct . I don't know y it got - ve vote.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying your application is crashing while inflating **Linearlayout class** at line number **1** in xml. Please check activity related xml file.

**Error**:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Linearlayout.